# How do I compile PHP with libcurl-gnutls?

Tags: php, gcc, compilation, gnutls

I have both the OpenSSL and GnuTLS versions of libcurl installed:

```
root@php-shared:/# dpkg -l | grep libcurl
ii  libcurl3:amd64                     7.38.0-4+deb8u2              amd64        easy-to-use client-side URL transfer library (OpenSSL flavour)
ii  libcurl3-gnutls:amd64              7.38.0-4+deb8u2                   amd64        easy-to-use client-side URL transfer library (GnuTLS flavour)
ii  libcurl4-openssl-dev:amd64         7.38.0-4+deb8u2              amd64        development files and documentation for libcurl (OpenSSL flavour)
```

Whenever I compile PHP from source (I'm using 5.6.16 here), it always links against the OpenSSL version of libcurl:

```
root@php-shared:/php/bin# ldd lsphp | grep curl
libcurl.so.4 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4 (0x00007f0fd38cb000)
```

I want to link against /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl-gnutls.so.4. I can't see anything in the configure that is appropriate.

I've just installed libcurl4-gnutls-dev and compiled, and now I see it linked:

```
twinter@php-shared:/var/tmp/php-5.6.16$ ldd ./sapi/cli/php | grep curl
libcurl-gnutls.so.4 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl-gnutls.so.4 (0x00007fdc1e47c000)
```

I guess what I'm asking is ... is there a way to reliably specify whether we want to link against the OpenSSL flavour of libcurl or the GnuTLS flavour? Or does it just depend upon which libcurl*-dev package you have installed? What happens if you have both?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Never mind. If I have libcurl4-gnutls-dev installed, I link against libcurl-gnutls, if I have libcurl4-openssl-dev installed, I link against libcurl. This is what I wanted to know :)